# Do Any JavaScript Test Frameworks Support ES Modules

Tags: javascript, testing, es6-modules

Do any test frameworks support tests that use the new ES Modules syntax? I have a JS application which heavily uses `.mjs` files with ES Modules.  I tried Jest and Jasmine, both of which throw errors when I try to write run tests for my app.  I need to test this file:

**math.mjs**

```
export function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Vitest is ESM-first and has TypeScript support out of the box as well: https://vitest.dev/guide/features.html

Answer (score 15):

As of February 2022, this is what I saw:

- **Jasmine**: [built-in support](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html#using-es-modules).
- **Jest**: built-in *experimental* support, [requires configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules) to code transformations and a node flag.
- **Mocha**: [built-in experimental support](https://mochajs.org/#nodejs-native-esm-support) lacks some features such as watch mode.
- **Tape**: built-in support (not mentioned in docs).
- **AVA**: built-in support (not mentioned in released docs, but there's [a recent commit to the docs switching all examples to esm](https://github.com/avajs/ava/commit/576f534b345259055c95fa0c2b33bef10847a2af))
- **UVU**: built-in support explicitly mentioned in the docs

Comment: Jest v.26 support for testing native ES modules is *experimental* and quite partial. May be enough for testing ESM code, but things like plugins still need .cjs work-arounds. v27 focus of extending the ESM support looks like a difficult goal. https://github.com/facebook/jest/milestone/12

Comment: Jest 27.5 still features ESM support as experimental -- support should be tracked here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430

Comment: 28 is in alpha https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases . I started using it and was able to withdraw my hacks regarding modules. :)

Comment: Mocha is kind of lying about their support: if you have any config at all (`.mocharc.js`, `.mocharc.cjs`, `.mocharc.json`) it puts Mocha into CommonJS mode, breaking all `import` statements.  So it works with ESM ... if you have zero configuration, or want to do all your configuration at the command line with arguments.

Comment: Vitest just worked, didn't even need to configure anything

Answer (score 7):

Other test runners with support for ES Modules are:

- **AVA**: AVA 4 [explicitly mentions ESM](https://github.com/avajs/ava/releases/tag/v4.0.0-alpha.1), but I've also used AVA 3 with ES modules without problems
- **UVU**: A [lightweight test runner](https://github.com/lukeed/uvu) that supports ES Modules and does not pull tons of dependencies into the project

Comment: I added AVA and UVU updated info to my answer, thanks for contributing.
I think this should be a wiki question.

Answer (score 6):

I tried [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/) and it worked like a charm. My goal was to build a publishable library with typescript. The library was part of a monorepo built with [Nx](https://nx.dev/)w with `"type": "module"` in `package.json` and the following in my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
}
```

It worked with 0 configuration, and I tried testing functions that used both CJS and ESM type imports from 3rd party packages.

On a side note, I really like the clean syntax. Plus, vitest also supports testing components built with React/Vue.

Comment: this saved me (solidJS project using vite)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `esm` package with Jasmine. Not sure about Jest though

**math.spec.js**

```
import { add } from './math.mjs';

describe('Add', () => {
  it('should add 3 and 2', () => {
    expect(add(3,2)).toBe(5);
  });
});
```

## Install and run

```
$ yarn global add jasmine esm
$ jasmine --require=esm
Randomized with seed 44366
Started
.
1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.004 seconds
```

Comment: For jest you can use babel.

Comment: converting es modules into commonjs is not the same as supporting es modules...

Comment: what converts ES modules into Common JS?

Comment: i guess you're right? `esm` just hacks into module loading, it is not really converting anything... is it?

Answer (score 1):

The project [Japa](https://japa.dev/) works with ESM and Typescript, and works perfectly in my set-up (Node.js 16.x with `"type": "module"` and `.js` files). The only [issue](https://github.com/japa/core/issues/57#) I got was easy to solve, so you should give it a try